# onclick event toggle div that is exists more than 1 in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I uploaded my code into jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r26q9ssu/
I'm trying to toggle the `div.que-answer` when I click on

`div.pull-left.circle.sh-answer`

```
    $("div.question div.sh-answer").click(function(){
    $(this).find("div.que-answer").show();
});
```

If u can see there is a multiple div called question, I don’t remember how to do that I am a little rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(this).parent().next()` instead [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/r26q9ssu/3/)

```js
$("div.question div.sh-answer").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next("div.que-answer").toggle();
});
```

Also if you want to hide siblings and add slide effect you can do it like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/r26q9ssu/7/)

```js
$("div.question div.sh-answer").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next("div.que-answer").slideToggle();
  $("div.que-answer").not($(this).parent().next("div.que-answer")).slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the final results with changing content:

```
$("div.question div.sh-answer").click(function() {
    if($(this).html() == '+'){
        $("div.que-answer").hide(300);
        $(this).parent().next("div.que-answer").toggle(300);
        $("div.question div.sh-answer").html("+");
        $(this).html("-");
    }else{
        $("div.question div.sh-answer").html("+");
        $(this).parent().next("div.que-answer").toggle(300);
    }
});
```